# Firebase Auth creating duplicate users for same email

Tags: firebase-authentication, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

When a user first logs in through Facebook on Firebase Auth, duplicate users with unique UID's are created.[image]

The peculiar issue is that I implemented login for this app months ago. An unrelated problem caused me to change my Firebase app. Since then new logins create duplicates. This is very hard for me to solve as the code I have implemented for login uses Facebook SDK and theres not much revealing whats under the hood. Also Firebase has an option that prevents users from creating duplicate accounts with the same email from different providers. But as you can see I am getting an erroneous user upon that initial login. Has anyone ever seen this problem? How am I suppose to fix it, when the problem is arising using the Facebook SDK?

Comment: Hey Kyle, I am assuming you are calling signInWithCredential using the Facebook OAuth credential. Do you happen to call it multiple times by accident. It is possible currently that multiple user creation requests (at the same time) with the same email could create duplicate users. The Firebase team is aware of this issue and working on a fix. In the meantime, check that you are waiting for the signInWithCredential to resolve before calling signInWithCredential again.

Comment: @bojeil. You are correct. I figured it out myself a little while ago. I had been calling the signInWithCredential twice. What might be useful information for anyone reading this, you will not notice this problem if the user requesting access has already been authenticated. For me I implemented login months ago, edited the code for some reason to have two calls, then later when i deleted my user UID on this part of the console and signed in; creation of two accounts was the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were two calls to signInWithCredential. FYI, this does not result in problems when the user has already logged in. So it could be a silent error that creeped up on you if you have the same problem.