# Firebase user authentication generates duplicate identifiers. Why?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Today, I am reviewing firebase for my project.
After a few tests I found the following screen.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhRVD.png)

As far as I know, identifiers should not be duplicated. (serious integrity fault.)

Firebase is a widely used service. 
So, many developers may know about this problem.

Because my project does not allow duplicate emails, could you share me the way how to handle this situation?

Comment: Any chance you're calling the `signIn` method multiple times? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40811879/firebase-auth-creating-duplicate-users-for-same-email.